# How to get page source as it is in browser and not in view page using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I know that `driver.getPageSource()` gets you the web page as Html but the issue I am having is that the site I am testing puts data in brackets like `{{OriginDescription}}`, maybe using some js framework to get the data? Anyway I can view the data when I inspect the element in browser but viewing the page source in browser also shows only the brackets and not the data. So how do I get the webpage as it is when I am viewing (inspect) it in the browser?

Below is the website I am testing to be exact:

```
driver.get("https://www.united.com/ual/en/US/flight-search/book-a-flight/results/rev?f=Miami,+FL,+US+(MIA+-+All+Airports)&t=IAH&d=2020-05-02&r=2020-05-16&sc=7,7&px=1&taxng=1&newHP=True&idx=1");
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
```

I am using java and chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for an element to load first, you can do that using:

```
driver.get("url");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TIME_IN_SECONDS);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("element-class-name")));

String page = driver.getPageSource();
```

This would wait for a page to complete loading and check is the element is clickable. Or, you can wait until the element is visible:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("element-id")));
```